# maven testCompile error: java 6 vs java 8

Tags: java, maven

I created a few Mock classes that implement java.sql interfaces (ResultSet, Connection etc.) 
When i run maven (3.3.9) test on my classes, i get a compilation failure (e.g. Class is not abstract and doesn't override abstract method getNetworkTimeout()) which is due to methods added in java 8.
I have JAVA_HOME set to Java 8.
I'm trying to compile my source and tests with java 6 and i have tried different methods:

1. adding properties for maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target to be 1.6
2. adding source and target configuration of 1.6 for maven-compiler-plugin
3. adding an executable for my 1.6 installation

None of them make any difference, which tells me i'm barking up the wrong tree.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the boot class path to use the 1.6 JRE; setting the language level only controls language features, not the classpath.